# Evaluating whether or not a particular sequence is monotone.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, monotone-functions

I am given the following sequence
$$a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n}$$
and asked to decide whether or not it is monotonic or not. My strategy has been to consider $a_n-a_{n+1}$ and see if I can evaluate the expression to greater or less than zero.

I broke the problem into two cases based on whether $n$ was even or odd. The first case went smooth as follows.

Suppose $n$ is even, then
$$a_n-a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}.$$

If I combine the $3^n$ fractions I get a $\frac{2}{3^n}$ so each term is positive and I know that $a_n-a_{n+1}>0$ whenever $n$ is even.

Now I was trying to work the some proces out for $n$ being odd. When I do I get to the expression
$$\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{2}{3^{n+1}}$$

I have been trying to compare the sizes of the positive and negative terms but I am finding it difficult to reach a conclusion.

Comment: Do you mean if it is monotone "from a certain step", or really monotone? Because I calculated $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ and it gave the answer.

Comment: You have a sign error, only the geometric term alternates.

Comment: Thanks. I think I found the sign error and fixed it.

Comment: Can you see if you can employ induction for this? $\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{2}{3^{n+1}}$

Comment: @ChristianHarris Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the first several terms rounded to  $$\{ .6666, .36111, .07407, 07484, .03588, .029149, .0199, .0157,.0122,.0100,...\}$$

Obviously it is not monotonic because the fourth term is larger than the the third one while others follow a decreasing pattern.
 It seems that after the fourth term it is decreasing. 
$a_n-a_{n+1}>0$
According to OP's statement for odd terms we have $$a_n-a_{n+1}= \frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{2}{3^{n+1}}$$

All we have to show is that $$\frac {1}{n^2}\ge \frac {2}{3^{n+1}}$$ or $$3^{n+1} \ge 2n^2$$ which is true for all $ n.$

Comment: Actually you just proved that the sequence is not monotonic. Most of the terms are decreasing except the fourth terms. I'll double check the calculation but even with the rounding the fourth term is clearly larger than the third which was what I was worried about showing. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any other way this can be proved apart from using the terms of the values? Most of real analysis exams don't allow for the use of calculator. Also, with sequences, we are not concerned about the behaviour of first few terms or anything. We are concerned about how the terms ultimately behave (hence, the notion of tails); so concluding that it's not monotonic based on just the 4th term is I think wrong.

Comment: Check my edited answer please.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=2k+1$

$$a_n-a_{n+1}=a_{2k+1}-a_{2k+2}=\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}-\frac{1}{3^{2k+1}}-\frac{1}{(2k+2)^2}-\frac{1}{3^{2k+2}}=\\=\frac{2k+3}{(2k+1)^2(2k+2)^2}-\frac{4}{3^{2k+2}}\stackrel{?}>0$$

which is true eventually since

$$\frac{\frac{2k+3}{(2k+1)^2(2k+2)^2}}{\frac{4}{3^{2k+2}}}\to \infty$$